# Unity 2d sprite editor bug

Tags: unity-game-engine

I cant edit[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOmaY.png) pocision in the sprite  editor as you can see in the image

Answer (score 0):

If sprite mode is in Polygon, position is not enabled. Set it to single or multiple type.

[image]

Comment: i checked tha and its set to single https://i.imgur.com/UQ853bq.png

Comment: Set it to multiple and that way position is available. That is to be able to subdivide a big sprite in smaller pieces. If single is selected, selects all the sprite so no position set. With multiple it unlocks, does it?